# Find the condition such that $A \cos{x} = x$ has exactly two solutions.

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

This is something we all do in high school but I forgot how to solve such a problem. It recently came up in my theoretical Physics research. I want to find a constraint on the variable $A$ such that the equation $A \cos{x} = x$ has exactly two solutions.

I started with plotting $y=\cos(x)$ and $y= \displaystyle{\frac{x}{A}}$ and so the limiting case of the solution seems to be when the line is tangent to the $cos(x)$ at one point and intersects it once. See [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY30o.png). Now, I don't know how to find the required condition. Much appreciate your help. Thanks.

Edited after corrections were pointed out. Added picture.

Comment: Sorry. Just edited it.

Comment: the figure is upside down. Meanwhile, the $x$  value where the tangency occurs, call it $x=B,$   happens with $B \sin B + \cos B = 0,$  so that $B \approx 2.798386 $ The slope of that tangent is $- \sin B \approx -0.3365.$

Comment: Thank you. That's one way to do it numerically.  I was looking for more of an analytical solution. Claude Leibovici's answer works well. But I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be easier is to consider the extrema of function
$$f(x)=\frac {\cos(x)}x -A$$ for which
$$f'(x)=-\frac 1{x^2}(x \sin (x)+\cos (x))$$

So, we need to find the zeros of function
$$g(x)=x \sin (x)+\cos (x)$$ Because ot the $x$ term, $g(x)$ will cancel closer and closer to $n\pi$.

So, make a infinte series expansion
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\pi  n \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)-(k-1) \cos \left(\frac{\pi 
   k}{2}\right)}{k!}\,(x-n\pi)^k$$ Truncate to some order and use [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to obtain for the $n^{\text{th}}$  root using $q=n \pi$
$$\color{blue}{x_{(n)}=q-\frac 1 q\left(1+\frac{2}{3 q^2}+\frac{13}{15 q^4}+\frac{146}{105
   q^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^8}\right) \right)}$$ Notice that using  Morse and Feshbach [generalization](http://www.astrosen.unam.mx/%7Eaceves/Metodos/ebooks/morse_feshbach1.pdf) we could have as many terms as required.

For example, using the above truncated series, converted to decimals, the first solution is
$x_{(1)}=2.79849$ while the "exact" solution as given by Newton mathod is $2.79839$ and the result will be more and more accurate.

This gives
$$A_{(n)}=\frac 1 q \left(1+\frac{1}{2 q^2}+\frac{13}{24 q^4}+\frac{61}{80
   q^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^8}\right)\right)$$